# System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

Tags: trigger, soql, unit-test, query

I have the below trigger which works perfectly but when I add an additional trigger, I get Error(System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 ) which is really worrying me. Basically i can't add another trigger and when I combine the additional trigger with the initial one I still get the same error. So far from my research the error seems to be caused by putting an SOQL query inside a loop but mine doesn't have that so i'm not sure how to solve this. Any ideas?

```
trigger UpdateLatestRecords on Student_Records__c(after insert, after update, after delete) {
    if( trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate ){
        list<Id> accIdList = new list<id>();
        list<Decimal> ExamValue = new list<Decimal>();

        for(Student_Records__c c : trigger.new){
            accIdList.add(c.Student__c); 
        }

        list<Contact> acc = [
            SELECT id, Latest_Overall_Marks__c 
            FROM Contact 
            WHERE id in: accIdList];

        list<Student_Records__c> examrecords = [
            SELECT position_in_class_F__c, Type_of_Exam__c, Overall_Marks__c, Name_of_school__c, Count_Number_of_Marks__c 
            FROM Student_Records__c 
            WHERE RecordTypeId in (
                    SELECT Id 
                    FROM RecordType 
                    WHERE Name = 'Student Exam Record') 
                AND (Type_of_Exam__c = 'Secondary End Term Exam' OR Type_of_Exam__c = 'Primary End Term Exam') 
                AND Student__c in: accIdList 
            ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];

        list<Student_Records__c> KCPEexamrecords = [
            SELECT position_in_class_F__c, Type_of_Exam__c, Overall_Marks__c, Name_of_school__c, Count_Number_of_Marks__c 
            FROM Student_Records__c 
            WHERE RecordTypeId in (
                    SELECT Id 
                    FROM RecordType 
                    WHERE Name = 'Student Exam Record') 
                AND Type_of_Exam__c = 'KCPE' 
                AND Student__c in: accIdList 
            ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];       

        list<Student_Records__c> KCSEexamrecords = [
            SELECT position_in_class_F__c, Type_of_Exam__c, Overall_Marks__c, Name_of_school__c, Count_Number_of_Marks__c
            FROM Student_Records__c 
            WHERE RecordTypeId in (
                    SELECT Id 
                    FROM RecordType 
                    WHERE Name = 'Student Exam Record') 
                AND Type_of_Exam__c = 'KCSE' 
                AND Student__c in: accIdList 
            ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];   

        list<Student_Records__c> feerecords = [
            SELECT Amount__c, Date__c, Name_of_school__c 
            FROM Student_Records__c 
            WHERE RecordTypeId in (
                    SELECT Id 
                    FROM RecordType 
                    WHERE Name = 'Student Fees Record') 
                AND Type_of_fees__c = 'Tuition Fees' 
                AND Student__c in: accIdList 
            ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];                                                                                                                                   

        If(examrecords.size() == 0){
        }
        Else{
            for(Contact a : acc){
                a.Latest_Overall_Marks__c = examrecords[0].Overall_Marks__c;
                a.Latest_Exam__c = examrecords[0].Type_of_Exam__c;
                a.Latest_Position_in_Class__c = examrecords[0].position_in_class_F__c;
            }

            update acc;  
            System.debug('///ENDTERM CONTACT FIELDS updated///');  

        }


        If(KCPEexamrecords.size() == 0){
        }
        Else{
            for(Contact a : acc){
                a.KCPE_Marks__c = KCPEexamrecords[0].Overall_Marks__c;
                a.Primary_School__c = KCPEexamrecords[0].Name_of_school__c;

            }

            update acc;
            System.debug('///KCPE CONTACT FIELDS updated///');
        }

        If(KCSEexamrecords.size() == 0){
        }
        Else{
            for(Contact a : acc){
                a.KCSE_Marks__c = KCSEexamrecords[0].Overall_Marks__c;

            }

            update acc;  
            System.debug('///KCSE CONTACT FIELDS updated///');  
       }

       If(feerecords.size() == 0){
       }
       Else{
           for(Contact a : acc){
               a.Last_School_Fees__c = feerecords[0].Amount__c;
               a.Current_School__c = feerecords[0].Name_of_school__c;
           }

           update acc; 
           System.debug('///FEES CONTACT FIELDS UPDATED///');
       }
   }

    if( trigger.isdelete ){
        list<Id> accIdList = new list<id>();
        list<Decimal> ExamValue = new list<Decimal>();

        for(Student_Records__c c : trigger.old){
            accIdList.add(c.Student__c); 
        }

        list<Contact> acc = [
            SELECT id, Latest_Overall_Marks__c 
            FROM Contact 
            WHERE id in: accIdList];

        list<Student_Records__c> examrecords = [
            SELECT position_in_class_F__c, Type_of_Exam__c, Overall_Marks__c, Name_of_school__c, Count_Number_of_Marks__c 
            FROM Student_Records__c 
            WHERE RecordTypeId in (
                    SELECT Id 
                    FROM RecordType 
                    WHERE Name = 'Student Exam Record') 
                AND (Type_of_Exam__c = 'Secondary End Term Exam' OR Type_of_Exam__c = 'Primary End Term Exam') 
                AND Student__c in: accIdList 
            ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];

        list<Student_Records__c> KCPEexamrecords = [
                SELECT position_in_class_F__c, Type_of_Exam__c, Overall_Marks__c, Name_of_school__c, Count_Number_of_Marks__c
                FROM Student_Records__c 
                WHERE RecordTypeId in (
                        SELECT Id
                        FROM RecordType 
                        WHERE Name = 'Student Exam Record')
                    AND Type_of_Exam__c = 'KCPE' AND Student__c in: accIdList 
                ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];     

        list<Student_Records__c> KCSEexamrecords = [
            SELECT position_in_class_F__c, Type_of_Exam__c, Overall_Marks__c, Name_of_school__c, Count_Number_of_Marks__c
            FROM Student_Records__c 
            WHERE RecordTypeId in (
                    SELECT Id 
                    FROM RecordType 
                    WHERE Name = 'Student Exam Record') 
                AND Type_of_Exam__c = 'KCSE' AND Student__c in: accIdList 
            ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];   

        list<Student_Records__c> feerecords = [
            SELECT Amount__c, Date__c, Name_of_school__c 
            FROM Student_Records__c 
            WHERE RecordTypeId in (
                    SELECT Id 
                    FROM RecordType 
                    WHERE Name = 'Student Fees Record') 
                AND Type_of_fees__c = 'Tuition Fees' AND Student__c in: accIdList 
            ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];        

        If(examrecords.size() == 0){
            for(Contact a : acc){
                a.Latest_Overall_Marks__c = NULL;
                a.Latest_Exam__c = NULL;
                a.Latest_Position_in_Class__c = NULL;

            }
        }
        Else{
            for(Contact a : acc){
                a.Latest_Overall_Marks__c = examrecords[0].Overall_Marks__c;
                a.Latest_Exam__c = examrecords[0].Type_of_Exam__c;
                a.Latest_Position_in_Class__c = examrecords[0].position_in_class_F__c;
             }

             update acc;  
             System.debug('///ENDTERM CONTACT FIELDS updated///');
       }

       If(KCPEexamrecords.size() == 0){
       }
       Else{
           for(Contact a : acc){
               a.KCPE_Marks__c = KCPEexamrecords[0].Overall_Marks__c;
               a.Primary_School__c = KCPEexamrecords[0].Name_of_school__c;
           }

           update acc;
           System.debug('///KCPE CONTACT FIELDS updated///');
       }

       If(KCSEexamrecords.size() == 0){
       }
       Else{
           for(Contact a : acc){
               a.KCSE_Marks__c = KCSEexamrecords[0].Overall_Marks__c;
           }

           update acc;  
           System.debug('///KCSE CONTACT FIELDS updated///');  
       }

       If(feerecords.size() == 0){
       }
       Else{
           for(Contact a : acc){
               a.Last_School_Fees__c = feerecords[0].Amount__c;
               a.Current_School__c = feerecords[0].Name_of_school__c;
           }

           update acc; 
           System.debug('///FEES CONTACT FIELDS UPDATED///');
       }       
   }
}
```

Comment: First thing should be having a proper indentation, without that its hard to identify query or DML inside a for loop. Second is if you are using after update trigger, best practice is to add a static flag check to avoid [recursion](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000133752&type=1).

Comment: Add your requirements clearly, please. It is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. I have added an answer on the basis of the error you've mentioned. But your code will need a lot cleaning and that won't be easy without knowing your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are number of problems in your code, let's start with

**Problem # 1**

```
list<Student_Records__c> examrecords = [SELECT position_in_class_F__c, Type_of_Exam__c, Overall_Marks__c, Name_of_school__c, Count_Number_of_Marks__c FROM Student_Records__c 
                                            WHERE RecordTypeId in (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Student Exam Record') AND (Type_of_Exam__c = 'Secondary End Term Exam' OR Type_of_Exam__c = 'Primary End Term Exam') AND Student__c in: accIdList ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];
list<Student_Records__c> KCPEexamrecords = [SELECT position_in_class_F__c, Type_of_Exam__c, Overall_Marks__c, Name_of_school__c, Count_Number_of_Marks__c FROM Student_Records__c 
                                            WHERE RecordTypeId in (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Student Exam Record') AND Type_of_Exam__c = 'KCPE' AND Student__c in: accIdList ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];             
list<Student_Records__c> KCSEexamrecords = [SELECT position_in_class_F__c, Type_of_Exam__c, Overall_Marks__c, Name_of_school__c, Count_Number_of_Marks__c FROM Student_Records__c 
                                            WHERE RecordTypeId in (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Student Exam Record') AND Type_of_Exam__c = 'KCSE' AND Student__c in: accIdList ORDER BY Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];   
list<Student_Records__c> feerecords = [SELECT Amount__c, Date__c, Name_of_school__c FROM Student_Records__c
```

**Issue with above code**

In Salesforce your priority number one is to beware of the [platform limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) and develop your code efficiently. Above, you are querying **Student_Records__c** object four times.

**Solution - Problem # 1**
Try something like the following to make your code efficient, and make [maps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) of exam type lists. They will be useful in the code scenario.

```
// maps with key=contactid, and value=student_record__c record.
Map<id, Student_Record__c> ExamRecordsMap = new Map<id, Student_Record__c>();
Map<id, Student_Record__c> KPCRecordsMap = new Map<id, Student_Record__c>();
Map<id, Student_Record__c> FeeRecordsMap = new Map<id, Student_Record__c>();
for ( Student_Records__c student : [SELECT position_in_class_F__c, Type_of_Exam__c, Overall_Marks__c, Name_of_school__c, Count_Number_of_Marks__c
                                    FROM Student_Records__c 
                                    WHERE Student__c in: accIdList ] )
{
    if(student.Type_of_Exam__c == 'Secondary End Term Exam' || student.Type_of_Exam__c == 'Primary End Term Exam') ExamRecordsMap.put(student.Student__c, student);
    else if (student.Type_of_Exam__c == 'KP Exams... ') KPCRecordsMap.put(student.Student__c, student);
    else if (student.Type_of_Exam__c == 'FeeExam') FeeRecordsMap.put(student.Student__c, student);
}
```

**Problem # 2** (not relevant to SOQL 101 error)

```
If(examrecords.size() == 0){
}
Else{
    for(Contact a : acc){
        a.Latest_Overall_Marks__c = examrecords[0].Overall_Marks__c;
        a.Latest_Exam__c = examrecords[0].Type_of_Exam__c;
        a.Latest_Position_in_Class__c = examrecords[0].position_in_class_F__c;
    }

    update acc;  
    System.debug('///ENDTERM CONTACT FIELDS updated///');  
}
```

**Issues with above code**

1. Why have a blank `if(list.size == 0)` check in which you are doing nothing? It creates visual noise and totally worthless. Use the following instead just put single check
   `if (list.size() >  0 )`
2. `update acc;`, I belive `acc` is the **list of contacts** you created earlier. Now, this will be a **DML** no matter there was any change or not, and that too **on the entire list** (also rename that list to [`contacts`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)). Have a list of Contacts-to-update and then build it as your code **conditions** are met and perform DML on that. It will only hold **valid** contact records that you actually want to update.
3. Your code is way too repetitive. Now, in a multi-tenant world of development, like Salesforce, this is not gonna work. You are taking big bites off the allocated **CPU time**. So, if not SOQL 101, you are gonna be hit by **CPU time limit exceeded** error for a batch of records.
4. There are other problems as well, like `List[0].Overall_Marks__c`, inside a loop on a `list` to refer another `list`, this will always index to the **zero** position record in that **referred** list. **Use maps instead** to refer them in such situations.
5. Comment your code, it really took me a long time to understand your code, without any description header and logical comments it was difficult and think of this as handing your code to your **code reviewer** in your company. He won't be very pleased. :)

**Complete Solution** (something roughly like [**La La Land… no wait, Moo Moo Moonlight**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111477/la-la-land-no-wait-moo-moo-moonlight))

```
trigger UpdateLatestRecords on Student_Records__c(after insert, after update, after delete) {
    if( trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate ){
        List<Contact> contactsToUdate = new List<Contact>();
        list<Id> contactIds = new list<id>();
        list<Decimal> ExamValue = new list<Decimal>();

        for(Student_Records__c c : trigger.new){
            contactIds.add(c.Student__c); 
        }

        list<Contact> contacts = [
                        SELECT id, Latest_Overall_Marks__c 
                        FROM Contact 
                        WHERE id in: contactIds];
        if (contacts.size() == 0  ) return; 


        // maps with key=contactid, and value=student_record__c record.
        Map<id, Student_Record__c> ExamRecordsMap = new Map<id, Student_Record__c>();
        Map<id, Student_Record__c> KPCRecordsMap = new Map<id, Student_Record__c>();
        Map<id, Student_Record__c> FeeRecordsMap = new Map<id, Student_Record__c>();
        for ( Student_Records__c student : [SELECT position_in_class_F__c, Type_of_Exam__c, Overall_Marks__c, Name_of_school__c, Count_Number_of_Marks__c
                                            FROM Student_Records__c 
                                            WHERE Student__c in: accIdList ] )
        {
            if(student.Type_of_Exam__c == 'Secondary End Term Exam' || student.Type_of_Exam__c == 'Primary End Term Exam') ExamRecordsMap.put(student.Student__c, student);
            else if (student.Type_of_Exam__c == 'KP Exams... ') KPCRecordsMap.put(student.Student__c, student);
            else if (student.Type_of_Exam__c == 'FeeExam') FeeRecordsMap.put(student.Student__c, student);
        }
        for(Contact con : contacts){
            if(ExamRecordsMap.get(con.id) != null) 
            {
                Student_Record__c examStudent = ExamRecordsMap.get(con.id);
                con.Latest_Overall_Marks__c = examStudent.Overall_Marks__c;
                con.Latest_Exam__c = examStudent.Type_of_Exam__c;
                con.Latest_Position_in_Class__c = examStudent.position_in_class_F__c;

                // build the contact to update list
                contactsToUdate.add(con);
            }
            else if(KPCRecordsMap.get(con.id) != null) 
            {
                Student_record__c kpcStudent = KPCRecordsMap.get(con.id);
                con.KCPE_Marks__c = kpcStudent.Overall_Marks__c;
                con.Primary_School__c = kpcStudent.Name_of_school__c;

                // build the contact to update list
                contactsToUdate.add(con);
            }
            else if(FeeRecordsMap.get(con.id) != null) 
            {
                Student_Record__c feeStudent = FeeRecordsMap.get(con.id);
                con.Last_School_Fees__c = feeStudent.Amount__c;
                con.Current_School__c = feeStudent.Name_of_school__c;

                // build the contact to update list
                contactsToUdate.add(con);
            }
        }
        // no need to check for list size here, as the dml won't be counted if "contactToUpdate" has no contact to update
        update contactsToUdate;  
            System.debug('///ENDTERM CONTACT FIELDS updated///');  

    }

    // delete event logic. 
    // follow similar pattern and where possible create functions with paramters to call them in handler logics. 
    // It reduces your code and simplies it to read and maintain.
    if( trigger.isdelete ){
        // delete logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Perfect, thanks a million @Mahmood. I even learned 2 new coding practices from this one post. Amazing

Comment: Getting error Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Student_Records__c in this line:       Contact examContact = ExamRecordsMap.get(con.id);

Comment: @RufusK. doh. change it to `Student_record__c examStudent = ExamRecordsMap.get(con.id); `. The map is returning a **Student_Record__c** object and hence it has to assigned to the same. I must have forgotten about it in haste. I have updated my answer, do check it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. If I wanted the SOQL queries to icnlude the record types, would "&& recordtype.developername == "example RT" work?

Comment: for that you would need to have the `RecordType.Name` in your `SELECT`. Something like `SELECT fld1, fld2, ..., RecordType.Name FROM Student_record__c WHERE ...` and then check in your code in `if` like you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Though by seeing your code there is no room which may lead to more than 100 SOQL queries in a single request but what i can suspect is that you trigger is getting into recursive mode and causing the issue.

The following link may help you

```
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000133752&type=1
```

Also the Context variable isExecuting will help you ..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't query the same table several times in the same transaction. Query each table only once.

E.g.:

```
for(Student_Record__c studentRecord  : [select id, name from Student_Record__c where student__c in accIdList]){

    if(Type of Exam == 'CKPE){


///do some logic    
}   

    else if(Type of Examp == 'KCSE'){       
//do other logic    
}   

else...

}
```